# WCF application for https binding on a IIS server

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, https

I am dealing with WCF programming. It was very smooth at the beginning. But it came with lots of difficulties after I use a https url binding. I read about WSHttpBinding, SecurityMode, SetCertificate from many articles and I still didn’t have successful results. I think I am missing something in several ways.

I’m developing on a Windows 10 PC and it runs a default website through IIS. I added a https binding through 443 port and apply IIS Express Development Certificate for SSL certificate. Every setting stays default.

1. Is it possible to run a WCF service application with https binding on a system which runs a https website?
2. What would I have to do to change the url to "**https://localhost:443**/MyService” in my code below?

Server project:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace studyWtfServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var url = @"http://localhost/MyService";
            var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), new Uri(url));
            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(iMyService), binding, url);
            host.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Service started: {0}\n(Press ESC to close)", url);
            while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape) ;
        }
    }

    class MyService : iMyService
    {
        public void SendMessage(string msg)
        { Console.WriteLine("Received from client: {0}", msg); }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    interface iMyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void SendMessage(string msg);
    }
}
```

Client project:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

namespace studyWcfClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var url = @"http://localhost/MyService";
            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            var ep = new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(iMyService)), binding, new EndpointAddress(url));
            var factory = new ChannelFactory<iMyService>(ep);
            Console.WriteLine("Input messages:(\"quit\" to close).");
            do
            {
                var msg = Console.ReadLine();
                if (msg.Equals("quit", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) break;
                factory.CreateChannel().SendMessage(msg);
            } while (true);
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    interface iMyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void SendMessage(string msg);
    }
}
```